# Disable Form Group via directive

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms, angular-directive

I'm having trouble trying to implement a directive I can use on elements with the [formGroup] attribute to set a condition for disabling the entire form group and it's form controls instead of imperatively calling `this.formGroup.disable()`.

I have a working directive for form controls that I got by searching the web:

```
import { Directive, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { NgControl } from "@angular/forms";

// use this directive instead manually enabling and disabling with reactive forms
@Directive({
  selector: "([formControlName], [formControl])[disabledControl]",
})
export class DisabledControlDirective {
  @Input() set disabledControl(condition: boolean) {
    if (this.disabled !== undefined) {
      this.toggleControl(condition);
    }
    this.disabled = condition;
  }

  disabled: boolean;

  constructor(private readonly ngControl: NgControl) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.toggleControl(this.disabled);
  }

  toggleControl(condition: boolean) {
    const action = condition ? "disable" : "enable";
    this.ngControl.control[action]();
  }
}
```

I tried something similar for form groups:

```
import { Directive, Input } from "@angular/core";
import { ControlContainer } from "@angular/forms";

@Directive({
  selector: "([formGroup])[disabledGroup]",
})
export class DisabledGroupDirective {
  @Input() set disabledGroup(condition: boolean) {
    if (this.disabled !== undefined) {
      this.toggleGroup(condition);
    }
    this.disabled = condition;
  }

  disabled: boolean;

  constructor(private readonly controlContainer: ControlContainer) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.toggleGroup(this.disabled);
  }

  toggleGroup(condition: boolean) {
    const action = condition ? "disable" : "enable";
    this.controlContainer.control[action]();
  }
}
```

But the form group isn't actually disabling properly. I set a breakpoint on the toggleGroup() method, and the status of the form group is "DISABLED" after, but on resuming the app, the form finishes loading and isn't disabled. I logged the formgroup out via button click afterward, and the status is "INVALID" again, instead of "DISABLED".

Any ideas on fixing this?

Edit:
I've done a very basic Stackblitz on this, and it seems to work on it's own:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-owlvqu?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Edit2:
There's nothing else that manipulates that form group, except at one point it is added via addControl() in ngOnInit() to a parent formGroup, but even taking that out the disabling still doesn't work while it does in the stackblitz, I can't figure out what might reset its status.

I tried to use ngAfterViewInit() in the group directive instead of ngOnInit(), and strangely, that works, it disables. I don't know if that is the cleanest solution though, better would be to know what further happens to the formGroup, but there's nothing in my code that would manipulate it.

Answer (score 0):

if you apply the directive to a formGroup, you need access to the formGroup in the constructor. For this you inject the FormGroupDirective

```
  constructor(private readonly form: FormGroupDirective) {}
```

we can make our function toggle that receive a FormGroup. A FormGroup is an object, so we need iterate using Object.keys

```
  toggleGroup(form: FormGroup, condition: boolean) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(key => {
        const control = form.get(key);
        control[action]();
      });
    }
  }
```

And in our input we call to the function passing the FormGroup (that it's under the FormGroupDirective.form

```
  @Input() set disabledGroup(condition: boolean) {
    this.toggleGroup(this.form.form, condition);
    this.disabled = condition;
  }
```

Well, this directive works if only has a FormGroup of FormControls, but what's happens if we has a sub FormGroup  inside our FormGroup ?, what about a FormArray?. Well we need take account if is a FormArray or a FormGroup because we iterate in different way. In any way our function should be recursive. So, we can transform our function like

```
  toggleGroup(form: FormGroup | FormArray, condition: boolean) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    if (form instanceof FormArray) {  //if is a FormArray
      form.controls.forEach(x => {
        if (x instanceof FormControl) x[action]();
        if (x instanceof FormGroup || x instanceof FormArray)
         this.toggleGroup(x, condition);
      });
    } else {  //if is a FormGroup
      Object.keys(form.controls).forEach(key => {
        const control = form.get(key);
        if (control instanceof FormControl) control[action]();
        if (control instanceof FormGroup || control instanceof FormArray)
         this.toggleGroup(control, condition);
      });
    }
  }
```

You has the directive in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-28x87c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdisabled-group.directive.ts)

It's only use (see that the formGroup is under form.form)

```
  @Input() set disabledGroup(condition: boolean) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    this.form.form[action]();
  }
```

Comment: That isn't really the problem though. I've already injected a `ControlContainer` instance in the constructor, which is just the super class of `FormGroupDirective`, so both would work. And there isn't any need to iterate over all children elements of a `FormGroup` to disable them, Reactive Forms already does that if you just disable the `FormGroup` by itself.

Comment: @Muffin, My good!!, you're ok, it's so simple to access to the form using the property "form" of the FormGroupDirective (thanks for the advise)